# Is it possible to create a pause other than adjusting the Unity Time.timescale?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I create a UI pause menu in Unity, I adjust the timeScale to make it pause. Is there any other way?

I want to adjust the pause in Unity not by adjusting the Timescale.

Comment: If the problem is the Time.time or Time.deltaTime, you have a unscaled version which are not affected by scale. If your problem is in the shader Time.time, you can pass a global 'float' shader param passing the unscaledTime through it. Define a name and them access it in every shader that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Pause Event and subscribe objects you want to pause. Then invoke your event and do pause-function on every object. For example:

```
public event Action Pause;

private void CallMenu(){
    Pause?.Invoke();
}
```

GameObject player:

```
private void OnEnable(){
    Menu.Pause += OnPauseCalled;
}

private void OnPauseCalled(){
    player.movement.enable = false;
}
```